# Can FireMonkey frames be created dynamically?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

FireMonkey has the option of using frames (not TFrame, which is a specific kind of visual component), which basically are collections of visual components which can be reused.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_Frames

However, there is nothing in the documentation about creating instances of frames dynamically, instead of placing them at design time on a TForm. Is there a way to create instances of a frame dynamically? When I try to do this, I get errors when attempting to access the frame in question's properties.

Comment: Yes, you can create frames dynamically. Why you are having errors is impossible to say without [mcve]

Comment: That's all I needed to know -  I didn't want to go on a wild goose chase trying to figure out what wasn't working. If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: FYI, I have now got the dynamic creation of templates working. I should note here that it seems the frame objects need to be assigned a unique Name property manually right after creation, at least when using C++, or the next frame object created of the same type will try to take the same name as the first one.

Comment: "*FireMonkey has the option of using frames (not TFrame, which is a specific kind of visual component)*" - they are indeed the same thing.  The URL you linked to even says so.

Comment: "If you add this as an answer, I will mark it as correct" Add *what* as an answer? That you haven't given a [mcve]?

Comment: @DaveNottage "*Yes, you can create frames dynamically*" - that is the answer

Comment: @AnthonyBurg "*However, there is nothing in the documentation about creating instances of frames dynamically, instead of placing them at design time on a TForm*" - anything you can do at design-time, you can do at run-time in your code. After all, the DFM has to create things dynamically when it is streamed in. You can, too. "*When I try to do this, I get errors when attempting to access the frame in question's properties*" - then you are doing something wrong, but we can't see what you are actually doing.  Please show your actual code.

Comment: @Remy re showing actual code, see my follow up comment, which was already posted when you added yours. It now works fine.

Comment: @Remy re them being the same thing, I was distinguishing between a default TFrame, and creating a customized frame using the 'File > New > Other > FireMonkey Frame'. This creates a new class which can then be customized, but which uses TFrame as the base class. In C++, at least, there is an important difference between a derived class and a base class. I was trying to distinguish between these two, so as to avoid answers such as alitrun's below.

Comment: @Dave Nottage, As Remy has noted, the answer is 'yes, you can make FireMonkey frames dynamically'. As I noted above, I didn't want to go on a wild goose chase if FireMonkey frames aren't designed to be created dynamically.

Comment: @AnthonyBurg "*re showing actual code, see my follow up comment*" - yes, you have to set a unique `Name` for a `TFrame` object, that is a LONG standing issue going back many many years.

Answer (score 1):

TFrame is a simple TControl, you can create and use it as usual Tcontrol component.
If you would change TFrame to TControl - nothing change because it is same.

```
var
  MyFrame: TFrame;

begin
  MyFrame := TFrame.Create(Self); 
  MyFrame.Parent := Self;
```

Self is TForm or any other TControl